# jQuery image gallery with flipping and rotating images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web, gallery

[image: Screenshot of demo]

I would like to make an image gallery using jQuery.

It is like a wall of images, similar to the one shown above which is demonstrated in [this video](https://vimeo.com/101056874). It would have each image automatically flipping and rotating, but not all at the same time. It is good have different images shown at a time.

I have put a lot of effort to search but can't make it.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vqmaw/5940/) and what I have done.

**JavaScript**

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults.timeout = 6000;
$(function() {
    // run the code in the markup!
    $('td pre code').each(function() {
        eval($(this).text());
    });
});

/*#S5*/
$('#s5').cycle({
    fx:    'shuffle',
    delay: -4000,

});

/*#S6*/
$('#s6').cycle({
    fx:   'shuffle',
    shuffle: {
        top:  -230,
        left:  230
    },
    easing: 'easeInOutBack',
    delay: -2000
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="demos">
    <div id="s5" class="pics">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>       

    <div id="s6" class="pics">
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like a very broad question. You should break it down into smaller questions. Do you need help setting up the grid of photos? Do you need help animating the photos? Do you need help with the layering of the photos? Your JSFiddle link looked like you were on the right track, it just needs more work.

Comment: when image start animating i want it to be rotate and than flip